# Rails nested attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR and this is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to use nested attributes to put records on 2 tables using just one form. This seemed so easy in the tutorial, but I'm doing something wrong and can't figure it out. 
I have checked other threads with similar problems with no luck.

Maybe you guys can help me.

Here are my two models

```
class Encuesta < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :encuestas_titulos_idioma, :dependent=>:destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :encuestas_titulos_idioma
end

class EncuestasTitulosIdioma < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :encuestas   
end
```

Ihave also set the permit for the nested attributes.

```
def encuesta_params
      params.require(:encuesta).permit(:estado, :servicio_asociado, encuestas_titulos_idiomas_attributes: [ :titulo, :descripcion, :encuesta_id ])
end
```

And here is the form

```
<%= form_for(@encuesta) do |f| %>
  <% if @encuesta.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@encuesta.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this encuesta from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @encuesta.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :estado %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :estado %>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <%= f.fields_for :encuestas_titulos_idiomas do |ff| %>
      <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <%= ff.label :titulo %>
        <%= ff.text_field :titulo %> 


      </div>
      <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <%= ff.label :descripcion %>
        <%= ff.text_area :descripcion, rows: 4 %>

      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any idea what is wrong?
Many thanks.

EDIT. THE FIX:

I found the problem (and the solution).
Here it is in case it can help someone.

In the controller *new* action, for a has_one association we should use

```
  def new
    @encuesta = Encuesta.new
    @encuesta.build_encuestas_titulos_idioma
  end
```

Not

```
@encuesta.encuestas_titulos_idioma.build
```

which we use for has_many associations.

Comment: did you received an error? can you check on the console if all data are be sent?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I got Unpermitted parameter: encuestas_titulos_idiomas
Then, I changed the name to singular (to match the accepts_nested_attributes_for parameter) but the error persists. Look like a naming convention error,but can't find it.

Comment: change `accepts_nested_attributes_for :encuestas_titulos_idioma` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :encuestas_titulos_idiomas`

And my suggestion is: use always english name.

Comment: I have already tried this with no luck. It needs to match the has_one name. I always try to use English names, but this is a job I'm doing for a client who want the names in Spanish.

Comment: check the logs (at the console) and see how the data are being sent

Comment: Thisi is the log:Started POST "/encuestas" for ::1 at 2015-09-13 01:51:07 +0200
Processing by EncuestasController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kDPdPHzucEnrMYHcP+zmLvz7n0JTs92hkAZQD/oopPPID/NMJ
y5Xgz4DulhSvE7tC+3p4xJhtFapYgsnjFjHJA==", "encuesta"=>{"estado"=>"0", "servicio_asociado"=>"sales",
"encuestas_titulos_idiomas"=>{"titulo"=>"test01", "descripcion"=>"testing"}}, "commit"=>"Create Encu
esta"}
Unpermitted parameter: encuestas_titulos_idiomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use inflections so that Rails knows how to get the singular/ plural of this non-english words

In `config/intializers/inflections.rb` add

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'singular', 'plural'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
params.require(:encuesta).permit(:estado, :servicio_asociado, encuestas_titulos_idiomas_attributes: [ :titulo, :descripcion, :encuesta_id ])
```

You must change `encuestas_titulos_idiomas_attributes` with `encuestas_titulos_idioma_attributes` because the associated has_one is: 
`encuestas_titulos_idioma` (singular: idioma).

And as says psantos: at the form too.

**Edit**
I also find at your post: `belongs_to :encuestas` at EncuestasTitulosIdioma class. Here replace with `belongs_to :encuesta`.

Comment: I did it before I posted the question, and the nested attribute fields didn't show up in the form.... This is driving me crazy

Comment: Just be sure that you are using `encuentas_titulos_idioma` everywhere. And not `encuestas_titulos_idiomas`

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
def encuesta_params
    params.require(:encuesta).permit(:estado, :servicio_asociado, encuestas_titulos_idioma_attributes: [ :titulo, :descripcion, :encuesta_id ])
end
```

and then:

```
# ...
<%= f.fields_for :encuestas_titulos_idioma do |ff| %>
# ...
```

You can keep the model like this:

```
class Encuesta < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :encuestas_titulos_idioma, :dependent=>:destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :encuestas_titulos_idioma
end
```

If the errors continues, show me how the data are being sent after these changes.

Comment: I already did that. And the problem was that if I changed it in both the permit and the form, the nested fields are not shown in the form.
Maybe I'm missing something in my controller...